# SUTime outputs the wrong week of the year

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, sutime

I was trying to use Stanford Temporal Tagger: [SUTime](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/sutime/process) for a NER task. It's a pretty decent tools. But it fails in a relatively easy date tagging related to the week of year. Here is an example: 
**The 2nd week of 2017** is tagged as **2017-W01**. If anyone is interested in trying, here where you can try different expression: [SUTime](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/sutime/process) I tried to dig deeper in the library implementation but in vain. Any clue on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, if this happens systematically, is that the week number is zero-based. Not sure if it was SUTime or HeidelTime, or another one, but think I encountered this with some temporal analyzer at some point (i.e. particular values being 0-based)

Comment: Well, I don't think so because when I tried the second week of 2018 it showed 2018-W02. Thus, I guess it has something to do with the first day of year: it counts the week that contains xxxx-01-01 as xxxx-W01 regardreless if it's W52 or W53 in the Georgian calendar.